# C# 4.0 Accessing form control from within Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

Code below runs OK. I wonder if it is really correct?

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(openFileDialog.FileNames, currentFile =>
    {
       try
       {
           StreamReader FileReader = new StreamReader(currentFile);
           do
           {
               URLtextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
               {
                   URLtextBox.Text += SelectURLfromString(FileReader.ReadLine());
               }));
           }
           while (FileReader.Peek() != -1);
           FileReader.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
     });
}
```

Otherwise I get either "Cross-thread operation not valid. Control 'URLtextBox' accessed from another thread" or stuck application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is correct - you need to use `Invoke` to refresh controls from outside the GUI thread. However, you are excuting the `SelectURLfromString(FileReader.ReadLine());` method in the GUI thread as well, you should replace that by

```
   string url = SelectURLfromString(FileReader.ReadLine());
   URLtextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
   {
       URLtextBox.Text += url;
   }));
```

to minimize the work in the GUI thread to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update UI controls from worker threads safely, unless you marshall onto the UI thread.

Take a look at [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx)

[How to: Schedule Work on a Specified Synchronization Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, you need the `Invoke` call so that the control is updated in the GUI thread.

However, there are some other things that doesn't really make sense in the code:

- You are doing parallel operations that is using a resource that is not parallel. Your threads will be fighting for attention from the disk, which is clearly the bottle neck due to it's relatively low speed.
- You will read lines from several files, and dump them intermixed in a textbox. That might be all right in this specific situation, but generally it gives an unpredictable result.
- You are using the `+=` operation to concatenate strings, a method that is notorious for it's bad scalability. It might not be a big problem in this case though, as the disk bottle neck is probably a lot worse.

Answer (score 1):

The Invoke is necessary because controls are bound to the thread that created their associated User32 window (often called an `HWND`).  That said, you could probably optimize a little by reading and processing the contents of the file outside of the `Invoke`'s delegate.